# Как на Java конвертировать таблицу Excel в Word?

Tags: java, excel, office, apache-poi

Сколько искал - не могу найти решения проблемы. Есть различные таблицы с различными полями и внешним видом. Нужно их каким-либо образом конвертировать в Word.

С 2010 в ворде есть функция вставки Excel Spreadsheet, но я не смог найти каких-либо инструментов, чтобы вставить таблицу из Excel в эту таблицу.

Текущее решение - это магия apache poi и модификацией кода не удается получить нормальную таблицу.

Comment: А что копи-пейст из Excel в Word никак? Обязательно надо через Java?

Comment: Да, никак. Да, обязательно нужно через Java. Или же через SAP Business Objects 3.1, но в последнем как раз импорт только в Excel.

Comment: Попробуйте получить выделить средствами apache-poi область в Excel и скопируйте его в clipboard, а потом в Word'е реализуйте вставку из clipboard. Сомневаюсь конечно. ИМХО можно попробовать скриптами какими нибудь ну например VB